# How to return two values from a function, that are created in the function? - Python

Tags: python

```
def FindingTwoPrimes(n, p1, p2):
    p1 = 0
    p2 = 0
    n = 0
    primeList = []
    for num in range(1,101):
        if all(num%i!=0 for i in range(2,num)):
            primeList.append(num)
    print (primeList)
    print ("Length of Primelist = ", len(primeList))
    lengthOfPrimelist = len(primeList)
    p1 = primeList[random.randint(0,lengthOfPrimelist)]
    p2 = primeList[random.randint(0,lengthOfPrimelist)]
    n = p1 * p2
    print ("p1 =", p1)
    print ("p2 =", p2)
    return n
    return p1
    return p2


FindingTwoPrimes(n, p1, p2)
print(p1, p2, n)
```

So above is a function that will find two primes that I will use in the method of the public key encryption system. However, when I run the function it returns p1, p2 and n back as 0. Why is this and how do I solve it? Also, any methods to make this code more efficient would be appreciated :-)

Comment: Use `return (n, p1, p2)` and then get them as: `n, p1, p2 = FindingTwoPrimes(n, p1, p2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be only one return in a function but you have 3. Change the below lines from

```
return n
return p1
return p2
```

to

```
return [n,p1,p2]
```

then change print statement as

```
print FindingTwoPrimes(n, p1, p2)
```

Also code in your function is wrong. Please change that as well

```
import random
def FindingTwoPrimes(n, p1, p2):
    primeList = []
    for num in range(1,101):
        if all(num%i!=0 for i in range(2,num)):
            primeList.append(num)
    lengthOfPrimelist = len(primeList)
    p1 = primeList[random.randint(0,lengthOfPrimelist)]
    p2 = primeList[random.randint(0,lengthOfPrimelist)]
    n = p1 * p2
    return [p1,p2,n]

print FindingTwoPrimes(10, 11, 12)
```

Comment: Why do you pass arguments to a function, if they are not used inside it?

Comment: Could be OP wants to do some more things inside function with first value n. That's why i didn't remove.

Answer (score 4):

Your function will return single value, because it execution will be finished after first `return` statement. You could return multiply values using a `tuple`

```
def FindingTwoPrimes(n, p1, p2):
...
    return n, p1, p2


n, p1, p2 = FindingTwoPrimes(n, p1, p2)
print(p1, p2, n)
```

Also, your code wouldn't work at all. In the beginning of function you assign zero values to all it args.

```
def FindingTwoPrimes(n, p1, p2):
    p1 = 0
    p2 = 0
    n = 0
```

Try to use variables with different names inside function.
As I understand, you trying to pass results back from function in arguments. This is bad idea. Use `tuple` to get results from function

```
def FindingTwoPrimes():
    p1 = 0
    p2 = 0
    n = 0
    ...
    return n, p1, p2

n, p1, p2 = FindingTwoPrimes()
print(p1, p2, n)
```

About last part of your question - how to make it more efficient. If you planning to call this function many times you could move `primeList` calculation outside of function.

```
def FindingTwoPrimes(primeList):
    lengthOfPrimelist = len(primeList)
    p1 = primeList[random.randint(0,lengthOfPrimelist)]
    p2 = primeList[random.randint(0,lengthOfPrimelist)]
    n = p1 * p2
    print ("p1 =", p1)
    print ("p2 =", p2)
    return n, p1, p2

primeList = [num for num in range(1,101) if all(num%i!=0 for i in range(2,num))]

print (primeList)
print ("Length of Primelist = ", len(primeList))

n, p1, p2 = FindingTwoPrimes(primeList)
print(p1, p2, n)
```

Answer (score -1):

for solve this only need

```
(n, p1, p2) = FindingTwoPrimes(n, p1, p2)
```

Comment: That's *not* the only change needed.